# Immigrated from UK to US in 2015: do I need to pay income tax twice?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, united-kingdom, foreign-income

A question regarding filing tax this year. I am a US green card holder. Until June 2015 I was working in the UK. I was on Work Visa. In June 2015 I immigrated to the US. Since then I work for a company in the US. 
Now it is time to do my taxes. I was wondering do I need to mention my earning in the UK? If yes, do I need to pay tax on that earning?

Some notes:

1. I paid all of my tax to the UK (HMRC) when I was there, I don’t owe them any money. So until June 2015 when I left that country I paid all of my taxes there.
2. I don’t have any assets there; I just have a bank account which has less than 10GBP in it.
3. I obtained my green card in 2014.
4. Since June when I left UK I don't have a valid visa anymore.
5. The tax year in the UK is 6 April to 5 April. In the US it is January to January.
6. While I was in the UK I didn't have any earning in the US and while I was in the US I had zero earning from UK.

Comment: Tax year in UK is 6 April to 5 April the following year. Have suggested an edit.

Comment: If you were on PAYE in the UK you might have *overpaid* there - it's often calculated on the assumption you'll work for a full year rather than just 2-3 months. Might be worth checking your payslips. Not sure what effect this would have on US liability, or whether it'd be reclaimable, though.

Comment: You can reclaim overpaid tax in the UK.https://www.gov.uk/claim-tax-refund/too-much-tax-taken-from-your-pay

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do. Since you've been a green card holder since the beginning of the year - your whole worldwide income for the whole year is taxable in the US.

You can take credit for the taxes paid in the UK (use [form 1116](https://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-1116)) to reduce your US tax liability.

Comment: so in this case did I needed to file my taxes in 2014 as well? if yes, is that gonna cause me any trouble that I didnt?

Comment: @eric_eri64 I don't know if you have to file, but you're definitely a US tax resident for 2014 as well, at least the part of it during which you had your green card.